# Combinar ficheiros TIFF num multi page TIFF C#

Tags: c#, array, arquivo, merge

Estou a fazer um programa para converter e concatenar ficheiros. Eu queria que, depois de converter os ficheiros PDF em TIFF, que os combinasse num só ficheiro multi page TIFF.

Ando à muito tempo à procura e ainda não encontrei nenhum código que funcionasse como eu queria.

Então eu converto os ficheiros PDF em TIFF e guardo-os numa pasta temporária. Depois tenho um array de strings que vai conter todos esses ficheiros da pasta temporária (através de uma função `GetFiles()`).

Quero que combine os ficheiros desse array num só multi page TIFF. 
Alguém tem a solução ou pode me direccionar para ela?

**EDIT** - O meu código:

Converter PDF em TIFF (com [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/))

```
public void PDFToTIFF(string output)
{
    MagickReadSettings settings = new MagickReadSettings();          
    settings.Density = new Density(500);

    string[] ficheiros = GetFiles();
    foreach (string fich in ficheiros)
    {
        string fichwithout = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fich);
        string path = Path.Combine(output, fichwithout);
        using (MagickImageCollection images = new MagickImageCollection())
        {
            images.Read(fich);
            foreach (MagickImage image in images)
            {
                settings.Height = image.Height;
                settings.Width = image.Width;
                image.Format = MagickFormat.Tiff;
                image.Write(path + ".tiff");
            }
        }
     }
 }
```

Função `GetFiles()`:

```
 public string[] GetFiles()
 {
     if (!Directory.Exists(@"C:\Users\srodrigues\Documents\ProjetoPAP-SofiaRodrigues\Main\temporario"))
     {

         Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Users\srodrigues\Documents\ProjetoPAP-SofiaRodrigues\Main\temporario");
     }

     DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\srodrigues\Documents\ProjetoPAP-SofiaRodrigues\Main\temporario");
     FileInfo[] fileInfos = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.pdf");
     ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
     foreach (FileInfo info in fileInfos)
     {
         if(info.Name != caminho1)
         {
             // HACK: Just skip the protected samples file...
             if (info.Name.IndexOf("protected") == -1)
             list.Add(info.FullName);
         }
     }
     return (string[])list.ToArray(typeof(string));
  }
```

Obrigada desde já.

Comment: Talvez seja mais fácil fazer tal merge antes da conversão, pra converter apenas um arquivo posteriormente não? Dê uma olhada neste tópico: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808670/combine-two-or-more-pdfs

Comment: Eu já tenho o código para fazer merge de PDF. Eu quero é converter em TIFF e fazer merge desses ficheiros...

Comment: Boas! Seria possivel disponibilizares o teu código ou o que já fizeste para termos uma base e te ajudarmos?

Comment: Olá, já incluí o código que já fiz. Há mais algo que eu possa melhorar na minha pergunta, visto que tenho -2 votos negativos @Mikev?

Comment: Acho que a pergunta ficou boa agora. No caso dessa questão não acho que negativar seria necessário, acho que apenas pedir o restante da informações que estavam 'faltando' e aguardar seria o suficiente (+1). Mas fazer oque, muita gente no site e muitos não pensam assim e são até um pouco chatos.

Comment: Acho que em vez de negativar imediatamente, propor alterações que vão ajudar a melhorar a questão, ajuda a quem faz a pergunta a saber como melhorar as suas questões, e ajuda a quem pretende ajudar, a compreender melhor o problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para fazer o merge de ficheiros TIFF num multi page TIFF, não é necessário nenhuma referência ou alguma biblioteca e terceiros, basta usar esta função.

Retirei a função deste site: [Split/Merge TIFF](http://dotnetconclave.blogspot.com/2013/03/c-code-to-split-merge-tiff-files.html)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

public void mergeTiffPages(string str_DestinationPath)
{
    string[] sourceFiles = GetFiles(); //deve criar uma, tenho o exemplo no código da minha questão
    ImageCodecInfo codec = null;

    foreach (System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo cCodec in System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders())
    {
        if (cCodec.CodecName == "Built-in TIFF Codec")
        codec = cCodec;
    }
    foreach (string file in sourceFiles)//para cada ficheiro no array de strings
    {
        try
        {
            EncoderParameters imagePararms = new EncoderParameters(1);
            imagePararms.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.SaveFlag, (long)EncoderValue.MultiFrame);

             if (sourceFiles.Length == 1)
             {
                 File.Copy((string)sourceFiles[0], str_DestinationPath, true);
             }
             else if (sourceFiles.Length > 2)
             {
                 using (System.Drawing.Image DestinationImage = (System.Drawing.Image)(new Bitmap((string)sourceFiles[0])))
                 {
                     DestinationImage.Save(str_DestinationPath, codec, imagePararms); 
                     imagePararms.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.SaveFlag, (long)EncoderValue.FrameDimensionPage);

                      for (int i = 1; i < sourceFiles.Length; i++)
                      {
                           System.Drawing.Image img = (System.Drawing.Image)(new Bitmap((string)sourceFiles[i]));

                           DestinationImage.SaveAdd(img, imagePararms);
                           img.Dispose();
                       }

                       imagePararms.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.SaveFlag, (long)EncoderValue.Flush);
                       DestinationImage.SaveAdd(imagePararms);
                       imagePararms.Dispose();
                       DestinationImage.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
        }
    }
```